# Sticky Header not staying totally fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I'm using [sticky.js](http://stickyjs.com/) to accomplish a sticky header. Everything is working except when I scroll down, the header moves up about 10-20 pixels and to the left about 10-20 pixels as well. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but if anyone knows why this might be, i'd really appreciate the help.

Here is a link to the site in progress http://barret.co/dad/services.html.

Any help or suggestions appreciated.

Comment: May I ask why you are using Javascript to make the sidebar fixed? Why not just set it to `position:fixed`?

Comment: You need to make sure that the styling that is applied by the javascript lines up with the styling without javascript. So there isn't any snapping.

Comment: Position fixed doesn't work properly because I am using a grid system. It's also responsive, so it's easier using a plugin.

Comment: All Sticky.js is doing is adding `position:fixed` when you start to scroll, it appears. At the point that it's being added, however, the text under `position:sticky` isn't in the same place as it is without that. Hence the sudden shift.

Comment: I just realized it must be somehow overriding my grid system. When I remove the margin from the top of logo it has a default 20px at the top that is created by the grid system. When it's scrolled, this padding is somehow removed. Trying to figure out why now.

Comment: @Barret Here is a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/T278u/) with your code.  you should strip it down to as little code as needed to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To counter the vertical movement, you'll have to instruct sticky.js (if possible, can't tell) to set the top of .sticker to 10 pixels (the top padding of the <aside> element), not 0.

Then:
the css for the logo image should be changed to something like this:

```
#logo {
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 25%;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

I removed the

```
display: block;
max-width: 100%; 
margin: auto;
```

as you can see. You'll have to play around with the left margin value to position it to your liking.

Then:
Because of the width of the .sticker element being in percentages, the actual width of the element changes when it becomes 'fixed'. This is because the element is now considered a child of the viewport and not the html parent element. This squishes your content from 310 to roughly 273 pixels. Set a width (in percentages) on your .sticker element that suits your design and be done with it.

Hope it helps!